# Error while executing the chromedriver in python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

Am facing the below error while executing the chromedriver in selenium-python.

**Error:WebDriverException: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home**

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="F:/SSN/SSN/Python/chromedriver")

Answer (score 0):

```
driver: WebDriver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/this can change/PycharmProjects/this is the title of the project/drivers/chromedriver")
```

SO in order to reach the above point:
1) Dowload Chromedriver (I guess you already did it)
2) On your project title (if you use pycharm it is up-left) and click dx to open the menu>New>Directory and give the name of the new directory "Drivers".
3)From Download forlder, or whatever position your chromedriver.exe file has been downloaded in step 1), take it and drag it into the "Download" folder.
4)Click right on the folder "Drivers">click on "Copy Path"
5)Past the "Copy Path" just after `driver: WebDriver = webdriver.Chrome("HERE")`

If this explanation sounds difficult just click here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDrFWRi13DY

Comment: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape, now am getting the above error

Comment: may you please share your coding? So I can see what could be the problem

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
driver = webdriver.chrome(executable_path='C:\Users\a02450\Desktop\Stock\chromedriver_win3\chromedriver.exe')

Comment: Even i add the r in front of 'c:\ & removed the executable_path= also am getting the same error

Comment: Sorry it is difficult to me to understand if you cannot share your code, because I am not an expert

Answer (score 0):

You can try as following

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'Path_to_chrome_Driver\\chromedriver.exe')
```

Please download chrome driver for selenium [Chrome Driver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads). Then enter the chrome driver location.

Note: Make sure you have downloaded the correct chromedriver based on your chrome browser version.

Comment: That last "Note:" is particularly important (and sometimes unexpectedly problematic).  Especially if you're using this system over a period of time.  When `Chrome` updates automatically, it can depart from the version of `Chromium` you originally downloaded.  The error message isn't super obvious, but if this works initially and later stops working, you may need to pull down a new version of `Chromium` to stay in sync with `Chrome`.