# Chrome WebDriverException using selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Before you rate me, I must say that I read almost every answer on this site about who had my same problem, but i found no answer.

For example [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49205782/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-chrome-not-reachable-err) the one who asked the question accepted the first answer, but copy-pasting the code in the answer the same error was raised.

An other example [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59435434/error-while-executing-the-chromedriver-in-python) where is linked [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDrFWRi13DY), which doesn't explain much, but there no error is raised, instead of my code when I copied it from the video. (he doesn't write .exe, so probably an error would be found in his code too)

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46074847/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-chromedriver-executabl?rq=1) has exactly my same problem, so it would be perfect, but no answer was accepted.

Here's the last line of the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chrome.exe %s' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

At the end of the exception message there's a [link](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home), which says they migrated to another site.

The error message here:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Impossibile trovare il file specificato

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

#Something else beetwen

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chrome.exe %s' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Here's the beginning of my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path)
```

I'm sure the path is correct, 'cause I copy-pasted it from the chrome.exe properties.

I also tried it without %s, and it raises a different error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0
```

Can someone help explaining me what's wrong?

Thanks

---

### EDIT

I searched with file explorer for "chromedriver", and nothing was found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as following

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'Path_to_chrome_Driver\\chromedriver.exe')
```

You are locating chrome browser exe location. Please download chrome driver for selenium [Chromedriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads). Then enter the chrome driver location.

**Note:** Make sure you have downloaded the correct chromedriver based on your chrome browser version.

Comment: chrome_path = r"C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = chrome_path)

Isn't it the same thing?

Comment: No. You are using Chrome Browser exe file. Please download chrome driver for selenium. Put in a location. Then enter the location in executable_path=r'Path_to_chrome_Driver\\chromedriver.exe'

Comment: Ok, I found it, there's no Win 64x version, I'll download 32x one

Comment: You can download from here. https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: THANKS A LOT it worked, I didn't know that chromedriver must be installed.

Answer (score 1):

As I see your path is to Chrome (browser) exe file instead of chromedriver.exe used by Selenium

Comment: C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe
C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s
C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chromedriver.exe
C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s
/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe
/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s

All this possibilities don't work

Comment: Do you have the chromedriver.exe file there?

Comment: i only have the chrome.exe file there... there's no file called chromedriver on my pc, and it's strange because I used chrome as main browser for months...

Comment: chrome.exe is BROWSER file. Selenium is not a bowser. You need chromedriver.exe to work with Selenium with chrome browser